# Adding components of a list together for BlackJack

Tags: python

I am making a BlackJack game for a project of mine. I made a deck of cards in a list, including ranks and suits, but when I try to add the hand of the player, I have only one value returning, instead of the sum.

I have no clue how to manage it. First I have to get all the elements of the list and then remove the suit to get a number, but some of my numbers are letters (Jack, queen, king, ace...) and have specific values to them. How can I add those together? I tried with for, while and other things, but in vain.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
def create_deck(): #this creates the deck of cards
    suit_string = 'hdcs'
    rank_string = '23456789TJQKA'
    global deck
    deck = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for suit in range(13):
            cards = rank_string[rank] + suit_string[suit]
            deck.append(cards)
            random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def deal_cards(): #This takes one card from the deck and gives it to the player
    return deck.pop(0)

def hand(): #Initial two cards
    global player1_hand
    player1_hand = []
    print "Player's hand:"
    for i in range(2): #initial cards
        player1_hand.append(deal_cards())
    print player1_hand
    print value()   

def value():
    i = 0
    while i < len(player1_hand):
        card = player1_hand[i]
        value = card[i]
        if value in ('T','J','Q','K'):
            return 10
        elif value == 'A':
            print "Please choose between 1 and 11."
            value_a = input("---> ")
            return value_a
        else:
            return value
    i += 1
```

Now this is what it gives me:

```
Player's hand:
['Ks','Th']
Value 10
```

I know I didn't really add the values together, but I have no idea how to manage it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Hope I was clear enough, as English isn't my main language.

Comment: Create a `Card` class/`namedtuple` that holds the card's rank and suit. Then, just write a `get_value(card)` function that computes a card's value.

Comment: I'm not sure how to manage that with class. I'm fairly new to python, could you explain a bit more in depth please?

Comment: Also please include your if __name__ == "__main__" statement or whatever else you are using to call your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `dict` of "rank values" you can just loop through the player's hand and total up the values.

```
def value():
    hand_total = 0
    # Add in a dict of "rank values" (excluding the Ace)
    rank_values = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8,
                   '9':9, '10':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}
    # No need for the while loop 
    for i in xrange(len(player1_hand)):
        card = player1_hand[i][0] # the added index will get the card          
        if card == 'A':          # without the suit.
            print "Please choose between 1 and 11."
            value_a = input("---> ")
            hand_total += int(value_a) # add a type check before this
        else:
            hand_total += rank_values[card]
    return hand_total
```

Using the `dict` you won't have to distinguish between face cards or numbered cards, just use the keys(cards) value and total the amount.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the help, everything works now! I tried each methods and they all worked fine. I'll probably use this one though.

Answer (score 0):

You've written a function `value()` that looks like it's intended to calculate the total value of `player1_hand`. But that function just returns the value of the first card it sees:

```
while i < len(player1_hand):
    if value in ('T','J','Q','K'):
        return 10
    elif value == 'A':
        ...
        return value_a
    else:
        ...
        return value
```

The `return` statement causes `value()` to return immediately, without continuing through the loop. I think what you want to do here is to have each step of the loop add the card's value to the total value of the hand:

```
total_value = 0
for card in player1_hand:
    rank = card[0]
    if rank in ('T', 'J', 'Q', 'K'):
        total_value += 10
    elif rank == 'A':
        print "Please choose between 1 and 11."
        value_a = input("---> ")
        total_value += int(value_a)
    else:
        total_value += int(rank)
return total_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well first things first there's a few errors in your code which could be causing some problems.

1) In your create_deck method both of the for loops are using the variable suit as their iterator, I'm assuming the first one should be set to rank instead?

2) You should end all of your methods with a return statement, even if they are returning nothing. This will force the method to quit and is good coding practice.

Ok, so to fix your issue you should make your value method read something like this. Right now you are exiting the method before returning the total value of the cards in the hand, only returning one value. To solve this create a global value outside of the while loop and add the value elements into it:

```
def value():
    i = 0
    total_value = 0
    while i < len(player1_hand):
        card = player1_hand[i]
        value = card[i]
        if value in ('T','J','Q','K'):
            total_value += 10
        elif value == 'A':
            print "Please choose between 1 and 11."
            value_a = input("---> ")
            total_value += value_a
        else:
            total_value += value
    i += 1
    print(value)
    return
```